# Can I develop an ipad app and distribute it to one client with a link?

Tags: ios, ipad, clients

I've read the related questions, but cannot find an answer for whether the following scenario can be solved on the apple platform.

- I want to create an app in Adobe Phonegap.
- I want this app to be deliverable to only one client with an iPad, with a simple link.
- The client is non-technical and very busy so if the app install process takes more than like 2 taps, - like having to register somewhere, it is not a good solution.
- Neither of us lives in the US

Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

- TestFlight
- HockeyApp
- An Enterprise Certificate

All of those will require one or two taps to install. ;-)

To use TestFlight in iTunes Connect for this, create the iTunes App Store entry as you normally would. Upload the build, and enable beta testing. You'll need the client's email address.

[Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) has a webpage that explains their distribution process: http://hockeyapp.net/features/distribution/

An enterprise certificate would work, but your use case is probably a violation of the terms of service and unless you're a company, you can't get one. I mention it because it technically would work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using hockeyapp.net for this purpose since it's free and generally works pretty well :)

Setup an account, upload your IPA, invite your client as a test user for your app.  Your client will need to setup an account on HockeyApp too, but it doesn't take long.

TestFlight is an option too, but it seems to have a harder time dealing with the heavy traffic load it's under a lot of the time.  Although it's air-traffic-control-themed error messages are cute...at least the first few times you see them :/